# When pasting any text to composed Gmail message cursor jumps back to the first line

Tags: windows-11, gmail, microsoft-edge

For about past 1-2 weeks I am struggling in my Microsoft Edge with the situation that when you paste anything to the message that you are composing in Gmail, then cursor lands at first character of the first line of the message.

Doesn't matter, if you paste with formatting (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) or without it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>).

Things that I have tried to resolve this issue:

1. Restart PC (Windows 11 Pro), browser (newest Edge) and Gmail.
2. Install all pending Windows Updates and update Edge to the newest version.
3. Run Edge in private mode.
4. [Run Gmail in "no-lab"](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?labs=0#inbox) version (`labs=0#inbox`).

All for nothing.

The problem is specific to Edge+Gmail only. I failed reproducing it in:

- Outlook.com
- RoundCube
- poczta.o2.pl Polish Provider's private webmail client

Issue cannot be reproduced in Firefox, neither for Gmail nor for any other mail client.

What else can I do?

Comment: Since Microsoft Edge also run in MacOS, you might want to add [tag:windows-11]. I'm not sure about how good is to use [tag:google-chrome-extensions] on questions that are no related to [tag:google-chrome] here in [su].

Answer (score 2):

Performing some more tests:

[image]

has revealed that the problem is caused by the famous *Night Eye* extension.

Disabling it:

[image]

solves the problem.

Fortunately, the issue happens in "pure" *Dark* mode only. If you setup Night Eye to display page in *Filtered* mode with i.e. very lowered *Brigthness* settings (33% in my case):

[image]

Then your eyes should be saved and the cursor problem does not appear.

Comment: good news. this issue has been fixed!